# Dynamic gallery does not work for me when it is set up in android

Tags: android, image-gallery

I'm a newbie to Android. I have a gallery in which images are displayed from URL. I cannot see the images when the gallery is set up for the first time, When I scroll the gallery, then all the images are set. I logged in `getView()` of Adapter (derived from BaseAdapter), and saw that `getView` works only after I clicked the item.
How to resolve this..

```
@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);<br>

    //method that displays image from url
    imageLoader.displayImage(myimageurls[arg0], activity, iv);

    Log.i("Gallery", "Image URL = " + myimageurls[arg0]);<br>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling notifyDataSetChanged() from your adapter right after the initialization of your gallery. This forces a redraw on that particular AdapterView (Gallery in this case)

JQCorreia